# Why does the Spotify Web API return status code 400 bad request?

Tags: python, api, spotify

I'm sure this is totally simple, but I'm completely new to using APIs. Using Python 3.8.2, just trying to get an album from the Spotify Web API but keep getting a bad request status. This is the code I'm using:

```
import requests
import json
from secrets import OAuth

swim = requests.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/{5zz3XzpeToFj5pa8CVX75S}",
                   headers={
                       "Content-Type": "application/json",
                       "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(OAuth)
                    }
                   )
print(swim)
```

OAuth is my OAuth token that I imported from a separate file. What information am I missing in my request?

Comment: Can you try removing `{}` in album_id? Make it: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5zz3XzpeToFj5pa8CVX75S`

Comment: I will post this as an answer, please accept :)